# Why is my NSNotificationObserver deallocated while a message runs on it?

Tags: ios, objective-c, automatic-ref-counting, nsnotificationcenter

I have a situation in which it can happen, that the last strong reference to an observer is removed while the observer processes an incoming notification.

That leads to the observer being deallocated immediately. I would normally expect, that a currently running method can finish before an object is deallocated. And this is what happens during normal message dispatch.

A simplified version of the code:

TKLAppDelegate.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "TKLNotificationObserver.h"

@interface TKLAppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) TKLNotificationObserver *observer;

@end
```

TKLAppDelegate.m:

```
#import "TKLAppDelegate.h"

@implementation TKLAppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

  // Create an observer and hold a strong reference to it in a property
  self.observer = [[TKLNotificationObserver alloc] init];

  // During the processing of this notification the observer will remove the only strong reference
  // to it and will immediatly be dealloced, before ending processing.
  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"NotificationName" object:nil];

  // Create an observer and hold a strong reference to it in a property
  self.observer = [[TKLNotificationObserver alloc] init];

  // During the manual calling of the same method the observer will not be dealloced, because ARC still
  // holds a strong reference to the message reciever.
  [self.observer notificationRecieved:nil];

  return YES;
}

@end
```

TKLNotificationObserver.m:

```
#import "TKLNotificationObserver.h"
#import "TKLAppDelegate.h"

@implementation TKLNotificationObserver

- (id)init {
  if (self = [super init]) {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(notificationRecieved:) name:@"NotificationName" object:nil];
  }
  return self;
}

- (void)notificationRecieved:(NSNotification *)notification {
  [self doRemoveTheOnlyStrongReferenceOfThisObserver];
  NSLog(@"returing from notification Observer");
}

- (void)doRemoveTheOnlyStrongReferenceOfThisObserver {
  TKLAppDelegate * delegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
  delegate.observer = nil;
}

- (void)dealloc {
  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:@"NotificationName" object:nil];
  NSLog(@"dealloc was called");
}

@end
```

Using the App Delegate in this way is no good style and only done for demonstration purposes, the real code does not involve the app delegate.

The output is:

```
 dealloc was called
 returing from notification Observer
 returing from notification Observer
 dealloc was called
```

That is in the first case dealloc is called before the notification processing finished. In the second case it behaves as I expected.

If I keep a strong reference to self inside `notificationReceived` the dealloc only happens after the processing. My expectation was, that ARC, the runtime or whoever else keeps this strong reference for me.

What is wrong with my code?
Or is something wrong with my expectation?
Is there any Apple- or Clang-provided documentation on this?

Comment: Isn't it looking weird for you, that object have no references and deallocating, but you remove it from `NSNotificationCenter`? If `NSNotificationCenter` holds reference at yours `TKLNotificationObserver`, then `dealloc` shouldn't be called.

Comment: NSNotificationCenter does not hold a strong reference on the observers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> My expectation was, that ARC, the runtime or whoever else keeps this
>   strong reference for me.

That is not the case, as documented in the [Clang/ARC documentation](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#self):

> The `self` parameter variable of an Objective-C method is never actually
>   retained by the implementation. It is undefined behavior, or at least
>   dangerous, to cause an object to be deallocated during a message send
>   to that object.

Therefore, if calling `doRemoveTheOnlyStrongReferenceOfThisObserver` 
can have the side-effect of releasing `self`, you would have to use
an temporary strong reference to avoid deallocation:

```
- (void)notificationRecieved:(NSNotification *)notification {
   typeof(self) myself = self;
   [self doRemoveTheOnlyStrongReferenceOfThisObserver];
   NSLog(@"returing from notification Observer");
}
```

A better solution would probably to avoid this side-effect.

Comment: That answers my question. Thanks a lot. I didn't find that. Perhaps because I was looking for the exact opposite.

Comment: And yes, you are right. In this case a have to rethink my design.

Answer (score 0):

the first dealloc probably happens as you set the observer property of the appDelegate twice and therefore the first instance is dealloced as soon as you set it the second time

Comment: That would be right, but the notification between the two assigns runs synchronously and be the time the second assign is executed the first lines of output are already printed.